# How to redirect http:// http://www and https://www to https:// using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do a wildcard redirect of http://example.com , http://www.example.com , https://www.example.com to https://example.com

I tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268353/using-htaccess-to-redirect-http-http-www-and-https-www-to-https) but it is not working for me as when i open any page, web browser shows too many redirects error.

The closest I have reached is I can redirect http://example.com and http://www.example.com to https://example.com using following code. But still can't figure out how to do https://www.example.com to https://example.com redirect

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Note (Maybe this is a problem causing too many redirects):
I just noticed that even without specifying any redirect code in .htaccess (see code below), `http://www.example.com` is getting redirected to `http://example.com`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are there any redirects in your host/virtualhost config file?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
#wordpress rules
```

Comment: same effect as my code.  `http://example.com` and `http://www.example.com` gets redirected to `https://example.com` but `https://www.example.com` does not

Comment: I just noticed that even without specifying any redirect code in .htaccess, `http://www.example.com` is getting redirected to `http://example.com` . Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the problem. SSL certificate was just created for `https://example.com`. I assigned a new multi-domain SSL certificate with both `example.com` and `www.example.com` and now things are working as expected. Here is my working .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```